# Moving a microservice to a different host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, traefik, moleculer

I have created a few micro-services using the "Moleculer" framework and am running each micro-service in a separate docker container (on a single host) using docker-compose. Traefik is being used as a reverse proxy. **I wanted to move one of the micro-services to a different host (with all of it's state preserved)**.

1. I used **docker commit** to create an image of the running container containing the micro-service I wanted to move to a different host.
2. I saved the image as a .tar file
3. I created a virtual machine with docker machine and copied the .tar file to the virtual machine using scp(secure copy protocol)
4. I loaded the .tar file using **docker load**.
5. I used **docker create** to create a new container
6. I used **docker start** to start the container
7. I stopped the container on the original host(the host from which the container was moved)

I get **Service Not Available Error** upon trying to reach the service moved to the new host.

Comment: seems more like the proxy is not set up correctly oO or do you get any indicating logs from the container after starting it ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean by "any indicating logs from the container". And I agree, this does look like proxy setup issue. But I am new to this and have no idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: basically look for any indicatino in the traefik configs for the url/ ip it was previously on and change it to the url/ip it is now reachable on (and preferably let soemone who configured it before double check :P)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Traefik is just being used with default configuration. It has just been added in docker-compose file like this.

'traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=INFO --docker.exposedbydefault=false
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "3001:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml'

Comment: so Im not a trafik expert but you probably need to setup your treafik .toml to do actual custom reverse proxing ( as far as Ive seen it mostly only does it semi-automatically for containers on the same host )

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Thanks a lot. I will look into it :)

Comment: what you wanna do is connect into the docker container of traefik and cat the /traefik.toml file (if it exists) just so no functionality gets delted and extend it by some variant of this 
https://serverfault.com/questions/850095/simple-reverse-proxy-with-traefik

Comment: You did not mention anything in your question about moving traefik to the new host. Could you please confirm that you moved your container only and you expect the existing traefik instance somehow to connect to a different host? Or did you move (or set up a new instance of) traefik as well?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I did not move the traefik container to the new host. I only moved the container that had the micro-service I wanted to move. Was i supposed to move the traefik container as well?

Comment: If you use docker integration feature of traefik then it discovers the containers by talking to the configured (or default) docker end point (socket). If you now have two separate docker daemons you have a problem as traefik can do the discovery from one only. So either configure it manually or you need second traefik. Or just use it directly without traefik. Depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I want to be able to use the service moved to the new host just as if it's available locally. Can you please explain how would I configure traefik to be able to talk to the service on the different host as well?

Comment: If you are running traefik on one docker machine but want it to forward your requests to other machine then you might need to use [file configuration](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/). In addition you need to configure your moved container to be reachable by traefik. Another option, is that you might want consider using docker swarm if it fits your scenario.